# Linux- Stop a process running as daemon

Tags: kill, services, uwsgi

I've started uwsgi as a daemon, how can I kill that process?

Everytime I `kill` its pid, and then does `ps aux | grep "uwsgi"`, it again comesin the output.

I've also tried `pkill uwsgi`, but no use. How can I kill it?

upon `ps aux | grep "uwsgi"`

```
root      2712  0.0  2.6 327540 26952 ?        Sl   17:03   0:00 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini conf_uwsgi.ini
root      2716  0.0  2.2 180076 22896 ?        S    17:03   0:00 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini conf_uwsgi.ini
root      2718  0.0  0.2   9396  2136 pts/1    S+   17:03   0:00 grep --color=auto uwsgi
root     16657  0.0  3.2 180076 32520 ?        S    Mar20   0:15 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini conf_uwsgi.ini
```

I `kill 2712 2716 16657`, and upon `ps aux | grep "uwsgi"` it again shows the same result with different PIDs. How do I kill it?

Comment: Depending on whether you are using systemd or sysvinit you may use "systemctl stop [service name]" or "service stop [service name]"

Comment: Nothing seem to worked. When `systemctl stop uwsgi`, it shows  `systemctl: command not found`. When `service stop uwsgi` it says `stop: unrecognized service`

Comment: Check your run level by using "runlevel" then go to the "/etc/rcx.d" file where "x" is the run level. For instance, if you are at runlevel # 2, then verify your service is at /etc/rc2.d/. Once there, stop the service by running the process like this: "./[processname] stop"

Comment: It would be `service uwsgi stop`.  The service name goes second.  How did you start the daemon?

Comment: Have you considered using `sudo kill -9 PID` it is "aggressive"  but effective

Comment: Read https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Management.html

Comment: @ott-- Thanks. It worked. Was searching for this for quite a long time

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by ott in the comments above, uwgi daemon can be stopped using following command.

`uwsgi --stop (location of uwsgi pid file)`